# Guarantee to iterate through all values in a multithreaded enviroment

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a `Set` with any type of values and an `AtomicBoolean` that indicates if the functionality provided by that class is running.

```
private Set<Object> set = new HashSet<>();
private AtomicBoolean running;
```

Now, i have two methods, one of them is adding objects to the set and the other serves as a setup method for my class.

```
public void start() {
    // ...

    set.foreEach(someApi::addObject);

    // ...
    running.set(true);
}

public void addObject(Object o) {
    set.add(o);
    if(running.get()) {
        someApi.addObject(o);
    }
}
```

However, there is a problem with that code. If the method is invoked from another thread while the `start` method is iterating through the set `running` is still `false`. Thus, the object will not be added to the api.

**Question:** How can i guarantee that all objects in the set and objects added with `addObject` will be added to the api exactly one time?

**My ideas:**

- use a lock and block the `addObject` method if the setup is currently adding methods to the api (or make both methods `synchronized`, which will slightly decrease performence tough)

Comment: Two solutions that come to my mind: use `synchronized` or do the initializiation in the constructor (and don't leak premature objects from the constructor).

Comment: Other than this, I would say the question is too broad and quite opinion-base. Of course, one could use `lock`s, or `semaphore`s. Or totally different concepts. Best would be to code up a solution, test it and, if it is faulty, come back and ask again.

Comment: @Turing85 Constructor initialization does not work for my use case, since the api is created in the same start method as well (would be too heavy for the constructor), but i suppose i'll go with the first approach then if there is no better one

Comment: what is the meaning of `running` variable? I suspect `AtomicBoolean` is not the right type for its role.

Comment: Use a concurrent collection: `CopyOnWriteArraySet` (the iterator will not reflect additions, removals, or changes to the list since the iterator was created). This will also eliminate the use of the flag (`AtomicBoolean` running). This may have performance hit as the `CopyOnWriteArraySet` uses `CopyOnWriteArrayList` internally (defined as: A thread-safe variant of `ArrayList` in which all mutative operations - add, set, and so on - are implemented by making a fresh copy of the underlying array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: How can i guarantee that all objects in the set and objects added with addObject will be added to the api exactly one time?

You have to be careful here because this gets close to the ole ["double check locking bug"](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/LCK10-J.+Use+a+correct+form+of+the+double-checked+locking+idiom).

If I understand you question you want to:

1. queue the objects passed into `addObject(...)` in the set *before* the call to `start()`.
2. then when `start()` is called, call the API method on the objects in the set.
3. handle the overlap if additional objects are added *during* the call to `start()`
4. call the method once and only once on all objects passed to `addObject(...)`.

What is confusing is that your API call is also named `addObject()`.  I assume this is different from the `addObject(...)` method in your code sample.  I'm going to rename it below to be `someApiMethod(...)` to show that it's not going recursive.

The easiest way is going to be, unfortunately, having a `synchronized` block in each of the methods:

```
private final Set<Object> set = new HashSet<>();
public void start() {
    synchronized (set) {
        set.forEach(someApi::someApiMethod);
    }
}
public void addObject(Object obj) {
    synchronized (set) {
            if (set.add(obj)) {
                someApi.addObject(obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To make it faster is going to take a lot more complicated code.  One thing you could do is use a `ConcurrentHashMap` and a `AtomicBoolean running`.  Something like:

```
private final ConcurrentMap<Object, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private final Set<Object> beforeStart = new HashSet<>();
private final AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean();
public void start() {
    synchronized (beforeStart) {
       for (Object obj : beforeStart) {
            doIfAbsent(obj);
       }
       running.set(true);
    }
}
public void addObject(Object obj) {
    if (running.get()) {
        doIfAbsent(obj);
    } else {
        synchronized (beforeStart) {
            // we have to test running again once we get the lock
            if (running.get()) {
                doIfAbsent(obj);
            } else {
                beforeStart.add(obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
private void doIfAbsent(Object obj) {
    if (map.putIfAbsent(obj, obj)) {
        someApi.someApiMethod(obj);
    }
}
```

This is pretty complicated and it may not be any faster depending on how large your hash map is and other factors.

Comment: @Grey Excellent answer, thank you for your time. I will go with the first solution, since it's simpler and my use case does not require such minor optimization.